# YouTube safeSearch=strict results drastically changed between 10/02/2013 and 10/03/2013

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I query the YouTube v2 api for `category=music` videos with `safeSearch=strict` option set. Previous to 10/03/2013 many music videos were coming through on the `safeSearch=strict` option, but starting on 10/03/2013 it seems these restrictions became much stricter filtering out many results that it did not yesterday. Is this an error? I don't know where to reach out to YouTube on this. Two example queries:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=katy+perry+roar&v=2&safeSearch=strict

versus

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=katy+perry+roar&v=2

return different results than it did previous to 10/03/2013. Yesterday the official video was the first result using safeSearch=strict and today it is not. The video is still the same identifier and the content did not change. This is happening for about 85% of content that my query strings have hit today. In my opinion, the content I'm querying is no where meeting their safeSearch thresholds. Can anyone shed some light or maybe point me to some resources I can read up on why this large change happened?

Comment: How do you expect people to know what is going on in the Youtube server backend? You should ask [Youtube support forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/youtube)

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. I filed an issue on the tracker - follow it and star it as well, hopefully it will be noticed. https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5336

Comment: Let's follow up in https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5336 This isn't an appropriate question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bug report.